# Linking to Home with LinkManager and languageEmbedding="always"

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore7

I am building a multilingual website in Sitecore 7.5, and I wish to always show the language in the beginning of the URL, e.g. `mysite.com/en/article1.aspx`.

To achieve this, I patched the `LinkManager` configuration according to [this](http://www.mikkelhm.dk/blog/patching-the-linkmanager) blog with `languageEmbedding="always"`. Now, when changing the language through `Sitecore.Context.SetLanguage()`, the URL changes correctly to the corresponding language code when following links as so on... So far so good!

The problem arises when I try to link to the home element, for instance through a redirect as such:

```
var homeItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(<GUID to home>);
var url = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(homeItem);
Redirect(url);
```

The resulting URL is `mysite.com/en.aspx` which shows a page called `Default.aspx` located in the website root folder. Of course, I want it to direct to `mysite.com/en/` instead, which corresponds to the home item in the given language and works if entered manually.

It seems to me that the `LinkManager` has a bug here, so it cannot correctly resolve the home item when embedding the language into the URL. Or is it just me who made a mistake?

Does anybody know a fix to this problem? How do I get the `LinkManager` to add the trailing slash?

**UPDATE**
Here is a screenshot of my content tree:

[image]

Comment: If you've patched the URL as described in that blog post, you *shouldn't* be getting the .aspx extension on your links. Sounds to me like your patching isn't working. If you look at your final web.config file, can you see your patched values?

Comment: Can you provide some detail around how you have your content structured please?

Comment: Have you tried setting addAspxExtension="false"?

Comment: @AhmedOkour I have tried with addAspxExtension to both true and false. The results are mysite.com/en.aspx and mysite.com/en respectively, but none of those show me the home item.

Comment: @timothyclifford The patching is certainly working (I used slightly different settings than those presented in the blog). What do you mean by how my content is structured?

Comment: Can you post a snapshot of your content tree, and post your site definition configurations?

Comment: Are you saying mysite.com/en/ does show you home item but mysite.com/en does not?

Comment: @timothyclifford Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @AhmedOkour I posted the content tree. I don't know what the "site definition configurations" are?

Comment: I think you're close, you're not appending the trailing slash which means Sitecore will look for an item named en rather than the website root for the English language. I think that's what's happening anyway...

Comment: But the question is: How do I get the `LinkManager` to append the trailing slash?

Comment: It is the default behavior from the LinkManager the /en.aspx url, but it should correctly render your homepage item.

Comment: In your website folder (e.g. `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\project\website`), delete the `default.aspx` page, it should solve the problem and stop Sitecore resolving to the file rather than the content tree

Answer (score 0):

About the default.aspx you get. That is possible a MVC thing you can fix it by adding a line in the global.asax in the Application_Start()
a System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
  System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
}
```

See [sitecore-and-the-error-page](http://sitecore.stockpick.nl/english/sitecore-and-the-error-page.aspx) and [john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2012/11/conflicting-files-mvc-routes-and-item-paths-in-the-sitecore-aspnet-cms](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2012/11/conflicting-files-mvc-routes-and-item-paths-in-the-sitecore-aspnet-cms.aspx)

I't don't change your url as you wish but it is default behaviour.

Comment: Thanks! I don't care if the URL ends with "/en" or "/en/", it just matters that the right item is shown. You can add this link to your answer as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21183998/sitecore-gives-a-blank-page-with-just-the-text-default-page-in-my-mvc-solution